# Oh, the Things I can Do

Tags: riddle, word

Many people use me at school,
As I am a useful tool,
They use me so they can save time,
However, sometimes, using me is a crime.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are of course

> A calculator

Explanation:

> The capital letters spell "MATH". Calculators are useful tools used to solve math problems, often in school. It can save you a lot of time. However, many tests forbid calculators, and using one would be considered cheating, which is a crime in some sense.

Comment: Where are the capital letters?

Comment: @ManojKumar In the riddle's text.

Comment: Sharp observation skills. Claps!

Answer (score 1):

A potential answer can be:

> Correction fluid.

Many people use me at school, As I am a useful tool, They use me so they can save time, However, sometimes, using me is a crime.

> self explanatory. Regarding saving time thing instead of making a document again because of some petty mistake one can use correction liquid over them. Its [abuse as an inhalant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_fluid#Abuse_as_an_inhalant) is a crime. Source Wikipedia